# java robot color checking in line

Tags: java, colors, awtrobot

What I need to do is get pixel color in horizontal line and if any pixel has the given color change the boolean value to false. It works fine when background contains only this color. Whats wrong with my code?

```
public class testAttack {
    public static boolean czyAtakowac = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        Robot myrobot = new Robot();

        for (int i = 704; i < 778; i++) {
            Color timerColor = myrobot.getPixelColor(i, 672);
            if (timerColor.getRed() == 136 && timerColor.getGreen() == 0
                    && timerColor.getBlue() == 21) {
                    czyAtakowac = false;
            }


        }
        System.out.println(czyAtakowac);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code looks ok to me, are you sure `getPixelColor()` works ok?

Comment: That might be a problem, i'll try to change my code to search for black -> if not black then stop.

Comment: You need to say what's wrong, and then maybe somebody here can explain why that happens. We don't know what you expect to happen and what really happens.

Comment: Your code should work

Comment: What i want to do is check if any pixel has the given color. If it has, then change permanently the boolean value to false.
I want to use that value to run the program or not.

For now it returns after each loop "true"

The error was in constatnly checking background, I changed to check if color is not black - and it works fine.
I guess i had to re-think it over the night :) thank You guys.

Comment: It seems that getPixelColor() is not accurate.

Comment: @CharlesMosndup Thats been 4 years. But thanks for the tip :)